# Pass Java Variables to Javascript Without Using Inline JS

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

Is this possible? I want to be able to pass java bean data into javascript objects, but I'd really prefer not to muck up my jsp pages with a bunch of inline script tags. I like to keep my javascript separate in external files, but how do you accomplish something like this without using inline js?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var variableFromServer = '${someBean.someProperty}';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a JSON file with all the data and either include it inline or fetch the JSON through Ajax - that way you don't clutter the markup with data. See http://json-taglib.sourceforge.net/ for an example of a JSP-JSON template.

Comment: This method may not be the easiest, but it seems to be the cleanest. I think all the responses would work well, but i'm accepting this answer because it is the route I chose to go.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is worth it but one alternative will be to set the desired value in an input filed with type="hidden" and get it's in js. But this will also pass this parameter in GET and POST request from the form.

Answer (score 0):

One option that I've used in the past is to configure the servlet container to run the JSP interpreter on `*.js` files.  How to set this up will depend upon what server you are running.

Note that if you want to access any request attributes this way you will need to set them up as part of the request that fetches the JavaScript file(s) (i.e. you will have to have a servlet in front of your JavaScript...or as an alternative you can use an `include` directive to bring in the scripts instead of a `<script src='...'>` tag).  Session attributes you can access without needing to have a custom servlet in front of your JavaScript files.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do what you're doing in the snippet (do you consider that "inline JS"?), create a div of JSON with data in it (exposed as a single string) and process it, pass JS files through the JSP process (or use a different templating system for dynamic JS pages), etc.

I'm not a huge fan of processing JS files through JSP; I'll often create an object containing all the info my JS needs in a `<script>` tag at the bottom of the body before including my real JS. It's kind of lazy, but it's straight-forward.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of doing it the simple and easy way, so I'd create a single script element that has a minimal number of JS variables set from Java - ideally a single JS variable that is set to an object with different properties for all the different bits of data you need to pass through. Your Java code basically just outputs JSON that will be interpreted as an object literal in the JS. Immediately after that include any external scripts - because they're included afterwards they can use the variables already created.

You can put the above in the head or at the end of the body. (Or in the middle, but that doesn't really make sense.)

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<!-- actual HTML markup here -->

<script>
     var variableFromServer = '${someBean.someProperty}',
         objectFromServer =  /* jsp to spit out JSON here as appropriate */ ;
</script>
<!-- external files included after the above will be able to access
     those variables -->
<script src="external1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="external2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="etc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

You certainly don't need "a bunch of inline script tags" - even if it doesn't make sense to put all the values in a single object at least create all the variables in a single script element, and then all of your other JS can be in an external file.

(Add namespacing as required.)